# Is it wise (or even code-compliant) to cut an access panel for my bathtub drain?

Tags: plumbing, drywall, bathtub

I am installing a replacement bathtub.  I've decided that I need to slightly lengthen my overflow pipe, and it would be kind of nice to be able to inspect that area well for leaks, before I put up the replacement wallboard and tile.

The other side of the wall behind the bathtub plumbing is a towel closet. I was considering the idea of cutting a square access panel in the sheetrock, at approximately where I've marked the picture with a red rectangle.

Are there any building code regulations I should be concerned with?  And is this generally a good/bad idea?  Are there best practices?

This is in the southern U.S.

[image]

Comment: It might be more useful, depending on the plumbing, to put it up higher behind the taps. The copper always has water, while the overflow is rarely wet. You're more likely to replace the valve than the drain without removing the tub too. (Just FYI they do sell clip-in access panel covers, so you may want to shop a bit prior to cutting.)

Comment: Good point (and I suppose I can always dangle a USB camera to look lower.)  Valve is replaceable from the front.  The manifold that the valve seats into is soldered to the pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a good idea to a very good idea.  I know of no code to restrict this.